# Access: SQL for Insert Into And Loop

Tags: sql, loops, ms-access, insert

I want to insert a value into column1. At the same time the value of column2 shall increase by 1 for each loop.

```
Private Sub counter_Click()
Dim strSQL As String
Dim column2 As Integer = 1
Do While column2 <= 1000

strSQL = "INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES ('" & Me!Value & "', "'+1'")
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL

Loop

End Sub
```

I tried this, but it clearly doesnt work....

Answer (score 0):

Just in case column 2 is of datatype numeric/Integer in your db. 
don't use ' ' with numbers : "1" instead of "'+1'"

EDIT: or +1 if this is the index of the loop

Answer (score 0):

-- I have slightly changed your code below are revised code. I have define strYourValue variable so you can set whatever value you want e.g. from textbox,dataset,dropdown etc.

```
Private Sub counter_Click()

    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim column2 As Integer = 1

    Dim strYourValue As String = "abc"

    Do While column2 <= 1000

        strSQL = "INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES ('" & strYourValue & "', '" & column2 & "')"
        CurrentDb.Execute(strSQL)
        column2 = column2 + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I get an error message in the Dim line, where I define the starting value of column2... "Compiling error"